# Size of an attachment?

Tags: metadata-api, attachment, tooling-api

Is there any api in salesforce to find out the size of an attachment?  I am creating package.XML in Salesforce and I would like to make sure that the size is less than 3 MB.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any api in salesforce to find out the size of an attachment?

You can find attachment size with a simple SOQL query (available via SOAP API) like so:

`select Id, Name from Attachment where BodyLength < 3000000`

Not quite sure why you mentioned attachment size with relation to package.xml though.
package.xml deals with Metadata while Attachment is Data and package.xml is not meant to deal with data.